# Pricing an OIS referencing SONIA with fixing lag

Tags: quantlib, interest-rate-swap, ois, libor-cessation

I'm trying to price an Overnight Index Swap referencing SONIA.

The swap will have a 5 day fixing lag (i.e using compounded SONIA over the current interest period but with the last rate set 5 days before the end of the period).

Can I simply do this using the MakeOIS function?

Comment: Are you asking for an analytical formula or solely the quantlib implementation?

Comment: @KevinT Solely the quantlib implementation... sorry should have made this clear! I guess the question is: how can I implement this using Quantlib?

Comment: I am no expert in QL, but I found [this thread](https://github.com/lballabio/QuantLib/issues/1089) on Mr @Ballabio's Git (he is a QL developer + also active in this forum, so he might be able to answer if he sees your question). Do note that the issue adresses the SOFR/SONIA *publication* delay but if you scroll down, you'll see that they also text about (shifted/unshifted) lookback & lockout, which seems to be what you're after.

Comment: That's correct — as of today the lag is still not managed in the OIS coupons.